# "greater than" symbol as closing php label

Tags: php

I'm stuck. My php code is reading a "greater than" symbol as a php code closing label. Here is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['log_u']) && isset($_POST['log_p'])){
    require 'sys/conn.php';
    $u=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['log_u']);
    $p=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['log_p']);

    $sLogin="SELECT id_usuario FROM usr_usuario WHERE usr_nombre='$u' AND usr_pass='$p' AND activo=1";

    $qyLogin=mysqli_query($conn,$sLogin);
    $nrLogin=mysqli_num_rows($qyLogin);

    if($nrLogin > 0){
   -- some php code -- 
   }
}
?>
```

This code reads everything up to the ">" symbol as php code, and then stops reading as php code and shows text on screen as normal or html code.

I don't know what's wrong in it. So please, anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: What is `-- some php code --`?

Comment: Look at the browser's page source - you will see _all of your code_ there.  What has probably happened is that your web server did not execute any of this as PHP. Does the file have a .php extension? Are you _using_ a web server to access the file, rather than opening it directly in a browser? (i.e. `http://localhost/thisfile.php` as opposed to `file:///path/to/thisfile.php`)

Comment: Is the PHP code prior to that actually being executed, or is it simply being treated as markup.... do a "view source" to check

Comment: Thank you all for your answers but it is already solved. That code is correct but Somebody has modified the code. It has been removed the line between "<?php" and "if(isset($_POST['log_u']) ...".

So, problem solved.

Thanks.